# Jena multiple rdfs:label

Tags: java, jena, ontology, owl, rdfs

I'm new to Jena and Owl I was given an ontology. I can open it with Protege 4.2 without any problems but when I try to open it with Jena I get:
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: {E201} Multiple children of property element`.

I have been looking a bit in my Ontology what it could be and I have noticed that some elements have more than one Label in a language for example:

```
<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
    <AbbreviatedIRI>atc:A02BX02</AbbreviatedIRI>
    <Literal xml:lang="no" datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">Sukralfat</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
    <AbbreviatedIRI>atc:A02BX02</AbbreviatedIRI>
    <Literal xml:lang="no" datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">antepsin</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
    <AbbreviatedIRI>atc:A02BX02</AbbreviatedIRI>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;string">sucralfate</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
    <AbbreviatedIRI>atc:A02BX02</AbbreviatedIRI>
    <Literal xml:lang="no" datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">sukralfat</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
```

Could this cause the problem? All the code I use works with other ontologies so I think it really comes from this ontology.
Do you know what could cause this exception?

### Edit

So I got down to a minimized case and still get the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE Ontology [
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY xml "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>


<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Rebholz-srv/atc/public/ontologies/atc.owl"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     ontologyIRI="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Rebholz-srv/atc/public/ontologies/atc.owl">
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Rebholz-srv/atc/public/ontologies/atc.owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="atc" IRI="http://www.legemiddelverket.no/Legemiddelsoek/Sider/Default.aspx#"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xml" IRI="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
    <Declaration>
        <Class abbreviatedIRI="atc:J"/>
    </Declaration>
    <AnnotationAssertion>
        <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
        <AbbreviatedIRI>atc:J</AbbreviatedIRI>
        <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;string">ANTIINFECTIVES FOR SYSTEMIC USE</Literal>
    </AnnotationAssertion>
</Ontology>
```

Here is the java code:

```
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(filename);
if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + filename + " not found");
}
model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
model.read(in, null);
try {
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't close the inputStream");
}
```

Does this help? I really don't have any idea anymore...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an [OWL2 XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-xml-serialization/) formatted file. Jena does't support that format, but it does support OWL in RDF/XML.

In other words it's expecting the wrong flavour of XML and getting confused.

Try saving it in another format.

Comment: Indeed this was the error. Does Jena supports turtle format? Cause I couldn't read the file in turtle format either. RDF/XML works though :) thx

Comment: Jena supports Turtle but as you open the stream and parse from the byte stream without the file name it can't guess the syntax.  Use model.read(in, "TURTLE").